# Retrievable logging in modular programing in C++

Tags: c++, c, logging, modularization

My task basically was to build a specific module for an existing system. The module works properly, but now I should place log entries inside the code. Since this is only a module of the final system the logging level should be configured outside the program, (which can be solved easily), and the main module should be able to reach the log entries of my module programmatically even if logging into command line or file is disabled. Do you know any existing logging library with this capabilities or that can be easily extended to have them?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [boost log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) will fulfill your request. It has a powerful source/sink system that will allow the main module to access our logs even if logging is disabled.

Here's a architectural overview:

[image: Architectural overview of boost log]

Comment: @user3017074: for an alternative you can also look up [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/); structure is basically identical, simply because there is not much ways to pass information "globally" :)